# Push Notification (FCM) not working in a test flight mode nor in a downloadable form

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to make my application work with a push notification service in a test flight mode ( essentially in a downloadable form, which is already in the app store ) but has worked in vain.

My IOS application was built with react native framework(0.39v). The application worked fine in the debug/release mode, being able to receive FCM sent from the API server or messages from Firebase console. Thinking it is ok to put the app on the appstore shelf, I uploaded the application and downloaded to my mobile. It worked expected except receiving Push Notification. It turns out that a testflight mode also shows malfunctioning of a push notification service. I am not sure why.

What would be the typical approach to deal with this issue? I reapplied the provisioning profile to the app but ended up failing. What would you recommend me to do? Might have this issue been triggered because of APNs certificate or Push Notification certificate?

If you have had similar issues, please them share with me!

Comment: What type of certifiacte do you use? Development or Production? Because for TestFlight version you should use Production cert for testing Push Notifications

Comment: I set development cert for debug mode and production cert for release mode at Xcode!

Comment: But what type of do you use for sending notifications?

Comment: I doubt this could be the issue of certificate.

Comment: make sure you have uploaded correct certificate for production mode in firebase console